# Adding Transaction ID to Return URL in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I currently have this in the code for my PayPal button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/successful.php">
```

However, I need to reference the transaction ID # in the URL itself.

I'd like users to be sent to a URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/successful.php?transaction=3j4kn543jkn435n
```

Is there any way to simply update the value of the return URL to have this added without needing to actually make any changes in my account related to IPN or PDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **[PDT](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/)**, the transaction id is automatically returned back to you in GET appended to your `RETURN URL`.

[image]

P.S As Andrew mentioned it is always nicer to use IPN which is more reliable and guaranteed unlike PDT(

- which does not work for Credit card payments
- if buyer closes the checkout page before being re-directed to your website)

Comment: You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

PDT is nice, but only for display purposes.  If you need to use that transaction ID to update your database, send emails, etc. you'll want to use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) instead, which is very similar to PDT except that the data will always be POSTed to your IPN listener, where-as with PDT, even if Auto-Return is enabled, there is no guarantee the user will make it back to your page.